# Inserting data into two mysql tables using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables named 'Students_tbl' and 'admission'. I want to insert admission number in both tables at the same time such that in the 'students_tbl', it is a foreign key while in the 'admission' table, it is a primary key. The 'students_tbl' has a primary key of "std_index"
I am using one html form.
The codes I have written are outputting an error. Thanks for your replies in advance

Here are the codes

```
<?php

$manzu =mysqli_connect("localhost","root","MANZu1992", "cdms");

// Check connection
if (!$manzu) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    echo "Please Check your connection. We were unable to connect you to the desired site.";
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $identification = mysqli_real_escape_string($manzu, $_POST['iddd']);
    $National_Number = mysqli_real_escape_string($manzu, $_POST['national_Numberr];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO students_tbl (std_index,std_national_number) 
    VALUES ('$identification','$National_Number')";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO admission (Admission_Number)VALUES($National_Number)";

    if (!mysqli_query($manzu,$sql)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($manzu));
    }ELSE {
        die ('Thank you for registering');
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: `$National_Number = mysqli_real_escape_string($manzu, $_POST['national_Numberr];` should be   `$National_Number = mysqli_real_escape_string($manzu, $_POST['national_Numberr']);`

Comment: Hello matt, I have included the last closing bracked ")" but instead the error the problem is that it is not inserting student index into the "students_tbl".

Comment: After `$sql = "INSERT INTO students_tbl (std_index,std_national_number) 
    VALUES ('$identification','$National_Number')";` put `mysqli_query($manzu,$sql)`

Comment: You're not executing the `$sql` before overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are missing a closing bracket and quote
2. You're not executing the first query before overwriting `$sql`

   ```
   <?php    
   $manzu =mysqli_connect("localhost","root","MANZu1992", "cdms");
   if (!$manzu) {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
       echo "Please Check your connection. We were unable to connect you to the desired site.";
   }    
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       $identification = mysqli_real_escape_string($manzu, $_POST['iddd']);
       $National_Number = mysqli_real_escape_string($manzu, $_POST['national_Numberr']);
       $sql = "INSERT INTO students_tbl (std_index,std_national_number)  VALUES ('$identification','$National_Number')";
       mysqli_query($manzu,$sql);
       $sql = "INSERT INTO admission (Admission_Number)VALUES($National_Number)";  
       if (!mysqli_query($manzu,$sql)) {
           die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($manzu));
       }else {
           die ('Thank you for registering');
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```